# How to tar a directory but exlude a file

Tags: linux, tar, gunzip

I want to tar.gz a directory but want to exclude a big file?  The is for intermediary extraction.  Dump will be written to and will want to keep.

```
E.g tar -zcf remote_test.tar.gz mydir/* except tsung.dump
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man tar`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar):

> ```
>  --exclude=PATTERN
>        exclude files, given as a PATTERN
> ```

So you can use

```
 tar -zcf remote_test.tar.gz --exclude=tsung.dump mydir/*
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an [exclude option](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/exclude-certain-files-when-creating-a-tarball-using-tar-command/) for tar. If you want to tar everything in `mydir` except a `tsung.dump`, the command would look like this:

```
$ tar -zcf remote_test.tar.gz --exclude='tsung.dump' mydir
```